# How to exit insert mode using autocommand upon losing focus?

Tags: vim

Currently, I am using the following command as suggested by [Auto save files when focus is lost](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto_save_files_when_focus_is_lost).

```
autocmd FocusLost * wall!
```

However, I cannot apply `<ESC>` trailing the `wall!`. Vim will complain about it and I *partially* enter normal mode. (The message-box actually takes the focus of cursor.)

Any suggestion on how to realize the action of: "auto-save + return to normal mode", upon "losing focus"?

Thank you!

All the best,

-Linfeng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `stopinsert`:

```
autocmd FocusLost * stopinsert | wall!
```

Comment: I am just aware that the "FocusLost" works in a limited way on Windows OS: it will only be activated when the "focus" is on another process (with anything other than `gvim.exe`). Any comment on how to have it autosave + exit insert mode even when I switch among Vim windows each having been started through different processes? Thanks!

Comment: have done in the following post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712464/how-to-let-vim-tell-the-switching-across-several-gvim-exe-processes