# How to let Vim tell the switching across several `gvim.exe` processes?

Tags: vim

Disclaimer: This question may be specific to Gvim on a Windows machine.

So far, `FocusLost` would be recognized when the "focus" gets switched from the `gvim.exe` process to any other process of different names. However, `FocusLost` will do nothing when I change from one `gvim.exe` process to the other. (In Windows OS, each `gvim.exe` process correspond to a "window".)

A working example of mine was introduced in this post: [How to exit insert mode using autocommand upon losing focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419274/how-to-exit-insert-mode-using-autocommand-upon-losing-focus/30419303?noredirect=1#comment49287084_30419303), where the refined command that saves the document + exit insert mode goes as follows:

```
autocmd FocusLost * stopinsert | wall!
```

The goal is to eventually enable auto-save when one leaves the active GVim window.

Comment: I don't know where you get the idea that FocusLost does not fire when switching between Vim instances; it does. I am running Windows 7 and launched two gvim.exe instances with `gvim -N -u NONE -i NONE`. I set up the same autocmd in each, `autocmd FocusLost * let a+=1`, set "a" to some value, and swapped back and forth between the windows with the mouse, and with alt-tab. "a" increments exactly as expected.

Comment: Same for me here; if you don't see this and can reproduce it, please report a bug on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).

Comment: @Ben @Ingo Karkat : It turned out at my end that the `autocmd` will be invoked 3-5 seconds after the condition is met. And, it does make a difference whichever process I am switching to. Do you guys have such "waiting time" at your end?

Comment: Not that I can tell.